# Powershell: Set-VPNconnection Change Name VPN, Rename VPN Name

Tags: powershell, vpn

I need found VPN connection with VPN address and change Name VPN.
I can found my VPN connection like this script:

```
Get-VpnConnection | Where-Object { $_.ServerAddress -like '*vash*' }
```

How I can change name VPN, because script like:

```
Set-VpnConnection -Name "Old Name" "New Name"
```

Will change VPN address not Name. How I can used powershell and this scripts, change name VPN connection?

Comment: You cannot rename a connection that is open.  You can delete and then create a new one.  Or where the connection is created open with different name.

Comment: Thx. I thinked about this and do exactly this way, remove and create new VPN, but I can't find how using powershell desable / uncheck IPv6 in new VPN connection?